# Closing RadWindow invoking javascript from server

Tags: c#, javascript, webforms, telerik, radwindow

Which method i should use to refresh parent page when I am closing the RadWindow.

Comment: You shuld probably manage the onclose event of the radwindow and use ajax to update just the needed controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be looking at using the Client Side `OnClientClose`, adding the javascript (e.g. `location.reload(true);`) in there to refresh the page (or just the necessary controls if possible).

See: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/clientsideevents/defaultcs.aspx